# Union of a null set and a non-measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $S$ is a non-measurable set (wrt the Lebesgue measure) and $N$ has measure 0. What can be said about $S\cup N$? Is it also non-measurable?

Comment: What is your motivation for thinking otherwise?

Comment: Note the answer depends on the _completeness_ of Lebesgue measure...

Comment: If a set  $S$ is measurable then  every set $S'$ such that $S'\Delta S \subset N$ is also measurable

Comment: It certainly could be nonmeasurable, but there is a theorem (whose name I am forgetting) which states that for every nonmeasurable set $S$, there exists a null set $N$ such that $S\cup N$ is measurable.

Comment: Have you tried it with a specific example, like Vitali sets and the set of rationals on [0,1]?

Comment: @Bey: Yes, that is precisely my reason for asking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $S \cup N$ is measurable.

Since $N$ is measurable, it follows that $N^c$ is measurable.

Therefore $(S \cup N) \cap N^c = S \backslash N$ is measurable.

Also, since $N$ has measure zero and since $S \cap N \subset N$, it follows by completeness of Lebesgue measure that $S \cap N$ is measurable.

Therefore $S = (S \cap N) \cup (S \backslash N)$ is measurable.

We showed that if $S \cup N$ is measurable, then $S$ is measurable. By contrapositive, if $S$ is non-measurable, then $S \cup N$ is non-measurable.